# I cant send a DM to the warned person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't make the bot send a DM to the person that I warn can someone help me or send me the full code, I'll appreciate that

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Color } = require("../../config.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "warn",
  aliases: [],
  description: "Warn A User!",
  usage: "Warn <Mention User> | <Reason>",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    //Start
    message.delete();

    let Member =
      message.mentions.members.first() ||
      message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

    if (!Member) return message.channel.send(`Please Mention A User!`);

    let Reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    client.db.add(`Warnings_${message.guild.id}_${Member.user.id}`, 1);

    let Warnings = client.db.get(
      `Warnings_${message.guild.id}_${Member.user.id}`
    );

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(Color)
      .setTitle(`Member Warned!`)
      .addField(`Moderator`, `${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id}`)
      .addField(`Warned Member`, `${Member.user.tag} (${Member.user.id})`)
      .addField(`Now Member Warnings`, Warnings)
      .addField(`Reason`, `${Reason || "No Reason Provided!"}`)
      .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(embed);

    //End
  }
};
```

Comment: Where do you ever attempt to DM the user?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see you attempt to DM the user. Add this to your code.

```js
try { 
  Member.user.send("this will be dm'd to user")
} catch (err) {
  // handle errors here
}
```